# Vista de clases apropiada para contener varios formularios de objetos distintos

Tags: django, django-forms, template

Quiero hacer una vista con tres secciones formularios para tres diferentes objetos, Prioridades, Estados y Tipos a saber. Tengo algo como [esto](https://pasteboard.co/GO87j9O.jpg).

Lo logré usando `modelformsets`, en una vista de listas, pero no sé que clase de vista utilizar para poder actualizar cada uno de los objetos independientemente: he intentado con `UpdateView` pero necesito un objeto general que devolver, `ListView` no posee un método post, y con las vista genérica tenemos el mismo caso.

Que solución debo implementar en este caso?

Comment: Yo te puedo ayudar, pero por reglamento del sitio, es necesario que adjuntes tu código a la pregunta, y no por enlaces, al igual que los errores, puedas colocar bien formateado el error, luego que hagas esto, me comentas y te respondo como solucionarlo

Comment: @GermanAlzate Hecho.

Comment: Ahora si, viendo tu formset, veo que está en orden todo, así que hay que debugear más el problema, por un lado, es ver si el formulario tiene campos invisibles, los cuales, debes asegurarte que se estén enviando también, lo otro, no sé como estás implementando la creación de formularios con javascript, pero debes asegurarte de actualizar los campos que arroja el `formset.management_form` ya que si estos datos no están correctamente diligenciados, django tiende a arrojar ese error, si tienes duda de como hacerlo, me dices

Comment: De hecho si tengo esa duda: estoy trabajando con `django-oscar` y no sé si hay algo de `Javascript` en ello.

Comment: Mañana termina la recompensa por esta pregunta @GermanAlzate.

Answer (score 0):

Hay algo que no comprendo de tu código, y es una curiosidad, quizás este no sea el error, pero no se de donde sale la variable `tag_formset`. En tus vistas no la veo definida, y al no estar definida, y llamar un atributo que sería el `management_form` pues simplemente el motor de template de django lo omite, y no arroja error.

En realidad no estoy seguro de para que sirve `django-oscar`, veo que es un plugin como de ventas online, pero no estoy si modifica el javascript, tampoco estoy seguro de que pueda estar afectando, solo debes asegurarte de que los datos de `management_form` se estén enviando de manera adecuada.

Para eso te digo que verifiques la petición, es bien sencillo, puedes hacerlo desde el lado del navegador, o desde el lado de la consola, desde el lado del navegador, si estas en chrome por ejemplo, luego de hacer click en el botón de submit, puedes ver en las herramientas de desarrollador, el apartado de `Network` y escoger la petición que haga match con la url actual, luego de ahí te vas a la pestaña de `HEADERS`, y bajas al apartado que dice `FORM DATA`.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La otra forma es desde el servidor, puedes ir a tu vista en tu método de `forms_invalid` y hacer un print de los errores del formulario. Puedes hacerlo por formulario, cuando los recorres, o el mismo formset de la siguiente forma `formset.non_form_errors()` O simplemente hacer un print de lo que venga en la petición antes de que el formulario lo valide, de esta forma `print(request.POST)`

Lo que debes validar, es que en la petición, se esté enviando estos parámetros:

```
'form-TOTAL_FORMS': '2',
'form-INITIAL_FORMS': '0',
'form-MIN_NUM_FORMS': '',
'form-MAX_NUM_FORMS': '',
```

Si esa información no sale en la petición, debes ver que ocurre en tu html, el por qué estos campos no se envían, entonces valida con javascript que los campos estén presentes dentro del formulario, estos campos son `type="hidden"`, así que solo los puedes ver si inspeccionas la página.

Asegúrate que esta información sea actualizable a medida que agregas formularios de manera dinámica en el javascript, de tal modo, que si envías 1 formulario el parámetro `form-TOTA_FORMS` debe ser igual a 1, si envías 2, pues igual a 2 y así sucesivamente, porque si no, la validación va a fallar, para los otros parámetros, puedes ver la documentación de django acerca de debe ir en esos campos.

Cualquier duda comenta.

Comment: No sé que pasa pero `StackOverflow` no está cargando las imágenes.

Comment: Ese `tag_formset` va incluido en la plantilla, yo incluyo en la plantilla principal una subplantilla cuyo parámetro es ese: le incluyo el `formset` adecuado para esa instancia.

Comment: Comprendo, ya verificaste que se estén enviando los datos que te dije?

Comment: De hecho he visto en la herramienta de depuración y he visto que todos los `formsets` tiene errores de validación:
```bash
 'priority_formset': '<<unhandled exception>>',
 'ticket_status_formset': '<<unhandled exception>>',
 'ticket_type_formset': '<<unhandled exception>>',
```

Comment: Definitivamente el problema está en los `form_set`.

Comment: Cuando yo quito la línea `POST` del código todo va bien. La página carga normal, pero cuando se la pongo, ya no sirve:
```python
formsets = {}
        for ctx_name, formset_class in self.formsets.items():
            formsets[ctx_name] = formset_class(
                self.request.POST,
                # instance=self.object
            )
```

Comment: ```bash
 'priority_formset': '<<triggers database query>>',
 'priority_list': '<<queryset of oscar_support.Priority>>',
 'status_count': 3,
 'ticket_status_formset': '<<triggers database query>>',
 'ticket_type_formset': '<<triggers database query>>',
```
Así debería verse normalmente.

Comment: Verifica que trae el `self.request.POST` si está trayendo bien los datos del `management_form` y por lo que acabas de comentar, te recomiendo que uses prefijos, el atributo `prefix=` de los formsets y formularios, para que los datos no se confundan

Comment: De hecho he visto el error, le estaba metiendo la petición dentro del métodod `get_context_data`, y con mucha razón no funcionaba.

Ahora tengo un último problema, una `ListView` no tiene el método `POST`, y una `UpdateView` requiere un objeto para actualizar. Que vista se acoplaría bien a esta vista que estoy elaborando?

Comment: Es la única pregunta que me queda, como los cuatro formularios son integrados como `form-sets`, de que forma integrar el método `POST` en esa vista?

Comment: Debo cambiar mi pregunta, verdad? O de paso eliminarla.

Comment: Si quieres modificala, y me avisas cuando la edites, con el nuevo código, o si quieres crear una nueva pregunta

Comment: Actualizado. Aunque el título no me convece.

Comment: Alguien por aquí?